# next.js modules are not loading I didn't know who to ask

Tags: next.js

to console
`npx create-next-app my-app`
I'm writing but I can't load modules and I get an error like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ENoo.png)
when i try to run it like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U7rX.png)

I was waiting for the project to run successfully, I want to start next.js but it's sad to get such an error from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off wifi and turn it back on. This was caused probably firewall reasons anyway try this:

```
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work